# Insert new row programmatically in TinyMCE

Tags: html, jquery, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE and I want to add a new row programmatically after a shortcut key is pressed.

I've the following code, to test the example [click here](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/lyhaab)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',
    plugins: 'table',
    menubar: 'table',
    toolbar: 'table',
    table_grid: false,
    height: 500,

    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+alt+a', "description of the shortcut", function() {
        alert('test successful'); //i want to insert a new row here
      });
   }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Make your code runnable here.

Comment: Sorry I cannot run it here as it's library is not available online. If you have any link please do share with me. The example is runnable and editable on the link I shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE uses commands to perform a lot of its functionality.  If you look at the existing functionality to insert rows above and below they rely on commands.  You can use a simple function in the `setup()` function in your configuration to see when TinyMCE uses a command:

```
editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
  console.log('ExecCommand:');
  //console.log(e);
  console.log(e.command);
});
```

What you will see from this is that there are two commands associated with these activities:

- `mceTableInsertRowAfter`
- `mceTableInsertRowBefore`

So you can associate your own keystrokes to these commands.  For example you can do this in the setup() function:

```
editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+alt+a', "description of the shortcut", function() {
  editor.execCommand('mceTableInsertRowAfter', false);
});
```

You can then setup one keystroke for inserting before and one for inserting after. Here is a TinyMCE fiddle that shows all of this in action:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/lyhaab/3

I setup two keystroke shortcuts:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for `mceTableInsertRowAfter`
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for `mceTableInsertRowBefore`